# Syntax error but I don't see it? (PHP/MySQLi_Query)

Tags: php, mysqli, syntax-error

So I have been working on different PHP scripts all day, so I don't know if it's just my eyes and I need a break or what: but I wrote a line to connect to MySQL database, and check if a username already exists.  However I get error messages of course that are less than helpful (even when searched they don't seem to apply to what I am working on or just simply don't show up anything.

Error one (before I put in or die(mysqli_error($myCon)):

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/icangame/public_html/dev/php/userRegister.php on line 40
```

Error Two (AFTER I put in the or die statement):

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== `user`' at line 1
```

Code that this apples to (will post more if you want, it's a big file.):

```
$checktherow = mysqli_query($myCon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` == `$realUsername`") or die(mysqli_error($myCon));
if (mysqli_num_rows($checktherow) == 0)
{
    mysqli_query($myCon, "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) 
        VALUES ('$realUsername', '$realPassword', '$email')") or 
        die(mysqli_error($myCon));  
}
```

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Besides fixing the syntax error, make sure to check into SQL injection. You should really consider using prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a break

replace

```
$checktherow = mysqli_query($myCon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` == `$realUsername`") or die(mysqli_error($myCon));
```

WITH

```
$checktherow = mysqli_query($myCon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = `{$realUsername}`") or die(mysqli_error($myCon));
```

NOTE `==` in your query

It was mysql syntax error so `$checktherow` is returning false

Answer (score 0):

The query is failing, so it assigns $checktherow a value of "false".  When you run mysqli_num_rows($checktherow), it is getting a boolean value instead of a mysqli_result object that it expects

The problem is your query, you have "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` == `$realUsername`", but it should be "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = `$realUsername`"

Comment: OH, Thank you.  I will mark this as the answer when it lets me!

Answer (score 0):

Dont use double equals when you want some specific from database , use it when you want to have comparison between values :

change this to :
          `username` == `$realUsername`

this:
          `username` = `$realUsername`

Answer (score 0):

```
$checktherow = mysqli_query($myCon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` == `$realUsername`") or die(mysqli_error($myCon));
```

should be

```
$checktherow = mysqli_query($myCon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` ='".$realUsername."'") or die(mysqli_error($myCon));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a single `=` sign instead of `==` in your first line. Like this
`$checktherow = mysqli_query($myCon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE`username`=`$realUsername`") or die(mysqli_error($myCon));`